# Update Patch Microsoft Graph API Planner Task Detail using JSON cURL produces error 409 conflict

Tags: rest, curl, microsoft-graph-api, filemaker, microsoft-graph-plannertasks

I receive a 409 error when trying to update a planner task, with the following error detail ... "The attempted changes conflicted with already accepted changes. Read the latest state and resolve differences."

It seems to happen every time I try to update the planner task.  I can literally create a new task, then try to update it and it immediately throws the 409 error.  No one has changed anything on the Microsoft side.  If I wait a few minutes, the same error occurs.

What's interesting is that if i run the update literally twice, back to back ... the second time it does accept the change without error.

The URL is: "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/planner/tasks/" & $microsoftplannerTaskID

CURL OPTIONS are:
"-X PATCH " &
" -H "Authorization: Bearer " & $$userToken & """ &
" -H "Content-Type: application/json"" &
" -H "If-Match: W/\"" & $microsoftPlannerTasketag &"\""" &
" -d @$PlannerTaskDetails" &
" -D $responseHeaders" //returns error codes

the $PLANNERTASKDETAILS are:
"{ " &
""bucketId": "" & #MicrosoftBucketID & "", " &
""title": "" & #title & "", " &
""dueDateTime": "" & $dueDateTimeFormatted & "" " &
"}"

Answer (score 0):

found that the issue was after an update, I need to get a new etag value before updating the same planner task again.  so you need to update, then get, then update again.